# Mongo db c# driver - how to join by id in collection?

Tags: c#, mongodb, join, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using Mongo DB c# driver 2,
I'm trying to **join 2 collections by ID (Many to Many)**

```
Class A
{
   public string id;
   public string name;
   public list<string> classBReferenceid; // <--- I want use this as the "keys" for the join
   public list<B> myBs;
}
Class B
{
   public string id; // <--- I use this as the "key" for the join
   public string name;
}
```

In my DB class "A" is saved without the data of "myBs" and I want to pull it from mongo in one call.

I tried to use the Lookup function:

```
IMongoCollection<A> mongoACollection = // already set in driver....
IMongoCollection<B> mongoBCollection = // already set in driver....

IAggregateFluent<A> results = _mongoACollection.Aggregate().
                Lookup<A, B, A>(
                    mongoBCollection,
                    a => a.classBReferenceid,
                    b => b.Id,
                    a => a.myBs);
```

But it doesn't work (doesn't join anything) probably because the "classBReference" is a list and not an "id".

How can I use the Lookup to **join a collection by id that appears in a list of id's in another collection?**

Comment: What is your mongo server version ? This will work starting 3.3.4 mongo version. More details here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22881

Comment: Thanks, I just saw a similar thread about this feature,
I used 3.4 .. But my embedded Mongo was 3.2

Comment: How can I do so that the `public list<B> myBs` is not written to db? I just want to use the `List<B> myBs` to represent the objects i C#, not write them do mongodb (since I already have them in the B-collection). If I use `[BsonIgnore]`, I can't do the Aggregate since it says it cannot serialize the list. Declaring the list as "virtual" (entityframework-style) doesn't work either, it sill writes the list to the "A" collection....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was introduced in MongoDb v3.3.4, but my local instance was using MongoDb 3.2 via Mongo2Go, which I use for unit tests.

Once I upgraded my local instance to v3.3.4, the issue was solved.

Comment: The example is in the question... Upgrading to new version make the code works

Comment: I could not find mongodb 3.x in nuget package manager?? mongocsharpdriver latest build is 2.7.0, MongoDb.Driver is 2.7.0.. Pls help

Comment: @Arjun version 2.7 of driver supports MongoDB up to 4.0. See https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/