# C# MongoDB JOIN Table outerKeySelector IN innerKeySelector

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, lambda

May I know how to join two table but table like this in `C#`, `Mongodb`

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM user where login_id LIKE '%a%') u
LEFT JOIN 
transaction t ON t.userId IN (u.usr_id);
```

Which mean join clause is using IN but not `=`

```
public class GameTransactions
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public List<UplinePt> UplinePts { get; set; }
}

public class UplinePt
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Decimal128)]
    public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
}

public class Users
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string LoginId { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to join Users into GameTransactions with clause UplinePts.UserId.
How can I join like that?

I'm newbie in C# MongoDB. Please give a guide. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongo db c# driver - how to join by id in collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944711/mongo-db-c-sharp-driver-how-to-join-by-id-in-collection)

Comment: Almost the same but my referenceType need get inside List<object>.Id not List<string>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can join two collections like this. one thing to note is that you must store GameTransactions.UserId as an `ObjectId` in mongodb or the joining won't work. because string and objectid comparison doesn't work.

```cs
    var transactions = userCollection.AsQueryable()
                         .Where(u => u.LoginId.Contains("a"))
                         .Join(transactionCollection.AsQueryable(),
                               u => u.Id,
                               t => t.UserId,
                               (u, t) => t)
                         .ToList();
```

here's a full test program:

```js
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class GameTransactions : Entity
    {
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public List<UplinePt> UplinePts { get; set; }
    }

    public class UplinePt
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
    }

    public class Users : Entity
    {
        public string LoginId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            var userOne = new Users { Name = "one", LoginId = "adam" };
            userOne.Save();

            var userTwo = new Users { Name = "two", LoginId = "bandwagon" };
            userTwo.Save();

            (new[] {
              new GameTransactions{
                  UserId = userOne.ID,
                  UplinePts = new List<UplinePt> {
                      new UplinePt { UserId = userOne.ID, Percentage = 10.1m },
                      new UplinePt { UserId = userOne.ID, Percentage = 20.2m }}
              },
              new GameTransactions{
                  UserId = userTwo.ID,
                  UplinePts = new List<UplinePt> {
                      new UplinePt { UserId = userTwo.ID, Percentage = 30.3m },
                      new UplinePt { UserId = userTwo.ID, Percentage = 40.4m }}
              }
            }).Save();

            var transactions = DB.Queryable<Users>()
                                 .Where(u => u.LoginId.Contains("a"))
                                 .Join(
                                    DB.Queryable<GameTransactions>(),
                                    u => u.ID,
                                    t => t.UserId,
                                    (u, t) => t)
                                 .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```